# Delete all data from all tables in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I use Sugar ORM 1.5 in my app and I want to clear all info when the user logoff.

I want to avoid deleting the database file or use pure SQLite scripts if possible.

The only solution I found was using deleteAll on all tables, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Regards,

**EDIT**

I solve the problem I had deleting the database just calling `SugarContext.terminate();` before deleting the database and `SugarContext.init(context);` after.

Looks like it's the best solution like Henry Dang pointed in the comments, and it is faster than deleting all data.

Comment: If your goal is to delete all the data in the app, then wouldn't deleting the database file be the most intuitive solution?

Comment: I had problems to delete the database, it only delete the database when I restart the app. In other hand, I want to know more about the Sugar's data manipulation capacity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This snippet works for me. It terminates the context deletes all tables and recreates them:

```
SugarContext.terminate();
SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator(getApplicationContext());
schemaGenerator.deleteTables(new SugarDb(getApplicationContext()).getDB());
SugarContext.init(getApplicationContext());
schemaGenerator.createDatabase(new SugarDb(getApplicationContext()).getDB());
```

SchemaGenerator is from com.orm, my SugarORM version is 1.5.

Comment: Deleting and recreating the tables will cause a delay every time... Is there any solution for just clearing records !?

Answer (score 2):

for other users who just want to delete all records (not tables or database)

```
public static void deleteAllrecords(Context applicationContext) {
    List<Class> domainClasses = getDomainClasses(applicationContext);
    for (Class domain : domainClasses) {
        SugarRecord.deleteAll(domain);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if we want to delete sequence also you can add this line inside for loop

```
            SugarRecord.executeQuery("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + NamingHelper.toSQLName(domain) + "'");
```